# Resize table columns inside a horizontal scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

[image]

I can resize columns like this using the highlighted handle. here I have resized First Name column. But if I put it in a div which has a fixed size and overflow is scrollable I can not resize columns more than the div width. 
Also it is not posible to resize more than the browser width even without the div. This is an angular project. Here is the code. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-18j1rt

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code and possibly create a JSFiddle?

Comment: this is an angular project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-18j1rt

Comment: Links will be broken, eventually. I suggest that you could paste the relevant part of your code here as well.